# Laravel 4 Mail function not working properly

Tags: laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I'm currently working on a web application which requires users to verify before they are able to use their account.
I'm using Cartalyst's Sentry to register the users, and sending the email using the built in Mail function, but whenever I register I get the following error:

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::__construct() must be an instance of 
Illuminate\View\Environment, instance of Illuminate\View\Factory given, 
called in 
/var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/MailServiceProvider.php 
on line 34 and defined
```

I can't figure out what causes this.
At the top of my code I included "use Mail" otherwise I would get another error:

```
Class '\Services\Account\Mail' not found
```

Code

```
// Create the user
$user = $this->sentry->register(array(
    'email'             => e($input['email']),
    'password'          => e($input['password'])
));

$activationCode = $user->getActivationCode();

$data = array(
    'activation_code'   => $activationCode,
    'email'             => e($input['email']),
    'company_name'      => e($input['partnerable_name'])
);

// Email the activation code to the user

Mail::send('emails.auth.activate', $data, function($message) use ($input)
{
    $message->to(e($input['email']), e($input['partnerable_name']))
    ->subject('Activate your account');
});
```

Anybody got an idea what the solution for this error is?

Thanks in advance,

Kibo

Comment: Have you updated your application between versions of Laravel?  Check out the upgrade notes: http://laravel.com/docs/upgrade

Comment: Thanks, upgraded from 4.1 to 4.2 and it works fine now!

Answer (score 1):

Remove /bootstrap/compiled.php I think it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove this from your Mail::send call. The function should be the third parameter so I'm not sure what you're trying to do here -- the $input['email'] field will already be available within the function due to your "use ($input)"

```
$email = e($input['email']
```

Comment: Forgot to remove that before since I had the $data array in the Mail::send as the second parameter first, but it hasn't solved my problem.